# Why do serialized DataContracts have bogus URLs in them?

Tags: c#, .net, datacontract

Depending on the size of my class almost half of the serialized text in `DataContract` classes is filled up with bogus URLs signalling namespaces of serialized classes, like this:

```
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Namespace/Of/Serialized/Class"
```

I get the schema part, and I also understand the advantage of signalling a specific namespace of a class, but the "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" part is completely useless as far as I can see. The site does not exist, and even if it were to exist I don't see how it should have any information about *my* Namespace.

Even if you were to say it's form of keyword to differentiate it from other XML Namespaces, they could have used a shorter one, and one that is not a ULR.

They're making my UnitTest harder to read, and take up lots of space in out Database. Can they be switched off? Can they be changed to non-URLs so my IDE doesn't show them as links? Can they be shortened?

Comment: Can be removed using `using System.Runtime.Serialization;
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Foo{}`.  For the point about readability and Db space I don't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because they're *URIs*, not *URLs*; their job is to be unambiguous and recognizable; it is *not* their job to point at anything. To quote from RFC 3986 §1.2.2:

> The URI itself only provides identification; access to the resource is neither guaranteed nor implied by the presence of a URI.

You can override the generated URI using the `Namespace` property of `DataContractAttribute`.